# Looking for best server setup solution for my web application

Tags: php, mysql, apache, nginx, mariadb

I have 3 codeigniter based application instances on two separate servers.
Server 1.
First instance is application, second instance is rest API, both use same database. ( I know there is no benefit to have two instances on same machine, other than cleanliness, and that is why I have it this way ).
Server 2.
This server holds only rest API with whole bunch of php data processing functions. I call this server worker because that is what it only does.
This server works as an endpoint for many API services I am connecting with.
So all this server does as first function is receive requests from application, sometimes it processes those requests before anything else.
Then sends requests to API service. Process is complete this session is over.
In short time API service responds with results where this server takes and processes the data then it sends the result to the application.

Application is at times heavy on amount of very simple sql queries, for the most part insert/update on single table. Amount of sent requests is kept to minimal as well, just because for the most part I send data as many requests in one. I call this bulk request.

What is very heavy is amount of responses I get, I can get up to a 1000 responses to one request within few seconds.( I can't minimize that, because I need every single one ), and then each response I get also is being followed by another two identical responses just to make sure I got it, which I threat as duplicate as soon as I can, and stopping that one process.
Then I process every response with php ( not too heavy just matching result arrays ) and post it to my rest API on the application server to update application tables.

Now when I run say 1 request that returns 1000 responses, application is processing data fine with correct results, but the server is pretty much not accessible in this time for other users.

Everything running on an (LAMP) Ubuntu 16.04 with mysql and apache.
Framework is latest codeigniter.

Currently my setup is...
...for the application server
2 vCPUs
4GB RAM

...for worker API server
1 vCPUs
1GB RAM

I know the server setup is very weak, and it bottlenecks for sure. But this was just for development stage.
Now I am moving into production and would like to hear opinions if you have any on how to best approach this.

I am a programmer first, then server administrator.

So I was debating switching to NGINX, I think I will definitely go with php-fpm, maybe MariaDB but I read of thread management is important. This app will not run heavy all the time probably 50/50 so I think just because of that I may not be able to set it to optimal for all times anyway, and may end up with not any better performance at the end.
Then probably will have to multiply servers and setup load balancing, also high availability.
Not sure about all this.
I don't think that just upgrading the servers to maximum will help tho. I can go all the way up too 64 GB RAM and 32 vCPUs per server.

Can I hear your opinions please?
Maybe share some experience?
Links to resources if you have some good ones?

Thank you very much. I hope you can help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

None of your questions matter.  Well, that is an exaggeration.  Machines today are not enough different to worry about starting with the "best" on day one.  Instead, implement *something*, run with it for a while, then see where your bottlenecks in order to decide what to do next.

Probably you won't have any bottlenecks for a long time.